# Split PHP array based on subarray values

Tags: php

Is there a PHP function, or other solution, that will facilitate splitting an array based on a value from it's subarrays?

**Yes, I know I can do this with a loop!** The question is if there's another way to do it without having loop through.

**Example:**

Using the value of Active, turn this array...

```
$array_all => Array
(
    [126] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Customer ABC
            [Active] => 1
        )

    [1596] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Customer 123
            [Active] => 0
        )

    [1648] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => John Q Sample
            [Active] => 1
        )

    [1649] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Fry & Leela, Inc.
            [Active] => 0
        )

    [1571] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Class Action: Redshirts vs. UFP 
            [Active] => 1
        )
)
```

...into this array...

```
$array_active => Array
(
    [126] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Customer ABC
            [Active] => 1
        )

    [1648] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => John Q Sample
            [Active] => 1
        )

    [1571] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Class Action: Redshirts vs. UFP 
            [Active] => 1
        )
)
```

... and this array.

```
$array_inactive => Array
(

    [1596] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Customer 123
            [Active] => 0
        )

    [1649] => Array
        (
            [DisplayName] => Fry & Leela, Inc.
            [Active] => 0
        )

)
```

Comment: `array_filter` or `array_reduce`?

Comment: there will be loops no matter what. why does every one ask for "with out loops"

Comment: @Dagon - Because sometimes it's nice not to have to loop through your data. Hence, language functions. For example, you could loop through a string and uppercase each character, but that's a common task, so PHP kindly provides strtoupper().  Yes, there are loops, but I don't have to deal with it every time I want an uppercased string.  Ditto for array_filter - it's a common task in my current project and I wanted to know if PHP had it built in before I built it myself.  Though I'm a bit embarrassed not to have thought of array_filter() which is literally the name of the thing I wanted to do...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$actives = array_filter($array_all, function ($row) {
    return $row["Active"];
}); 

$notActives = array_filter($array_all, function ($row) {
    return !$row["Active"];
});
```

You can also use [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) as alternative, but it returns indexed arrays, so without the original keys:

```
list($actives, $notActives) = array_reduce($array_all, function ($result, $row) {
    $result[$row["Active"]][] = $row;
    return $result;
}, [[],[]]);
```

When using `array_reduce` to also maintain keys, it becomes quite verbose:

```
list($actives, $notActives) = array_reduce(array_keys($array_all), 
    function ($result, $key) use ($array_all) {
        $result[$array_all[$key]["Active"]][$key] = $array_all[$key];
        return $result;
    }, [[],[]]
);
```