# How to split or fetch value of sub-array from main array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, php-7

I would like to get values of sub-array from main. Following is my array.

```
 [tour_avaibility] => Array
        (
            [tour_avaibility_location] => Array
                (
                    [Location_one] => Location_two
                    [Location_seven] => Location_nine
                )

            [tour_avaibility_date] => Array
                (
                    [02/11/2020] => 02/17/2020
                    [02/21/2020] => 02/26/2020
                )

        )
```

I want `'tour_avaibility_location'` & `tour_avaibility_date` value through only one loop. I used following code but it repeat value.

```
<?php
foreach ($tourAvaibilityDate['tour_avaibility'] as $key => $value) {?>
    <div class="other-tag justify-content-between">
            <?php
            foreach ( array_unique($tourAvaibilityLocation['tour_avaibility']['tour_avaibility_location'] ) as $k => $v) {?>    
                <div class="tag-name"><?php echo $k.$v; ?></div>
            <?php }?>

            <?php
            foreach ( array_unique($tourAvaibilityDate['tour_avaibility']['tour_avaibility_date'] ) as $k => $v) {?>    
            <div class="tag-price">25 Nov 2019 - 30 Nov 2019</div>
            <?php } ?>
        <div class="tag-remove text-light">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I want out put like..

```
Location_one - Location_two  02/11/2020 - 02/17/2020
Location_seven - Location_nine  02/21/2020 - 02/26/2020
```

Comment: Just replace `25 Nov 2019 - 30 Nov 2019` with `$k . ' - ' . $v` like you did for the locations

Comment: I already tried Not work, it's given output like "Location_one - Location_two  02/11/2020 - 02/17/2020 Location_seven - Location_nine  02/21/2020 - 02/26/2020 "
Location_one - Location_two  02/11/2020 - 02/17/2020 Location_seven - Location_nine  02/21/2020 - 02/26/2020.

It's repeater same value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split PHP array based on subarray values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063211/split-php-array-based-on-subarray-values)

Comment: @RaviMakwana , Nope

Comment: I'm Also try to create a demo same as @Nick, so here you have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to separate out the keys and values of each array in `$tourAvaibilityDate['tour_avaibility']`; then you can iterate over them. Note this code assumes there is the same number of dates as locations:

```
$tours = $tourAvaibilityDate['tour_avaibility'];
$start_locations = array_keys($tours['tour_avaibility_location']);
$end_locations = array_values($tours['tour_avaibility_location']);
$start_dates = array_keys($tours['tour_avaibility_date']);
$end_dates = array_values($tours['tour_avaibility_date']);
$c = count($start_locations);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    echo $start_locations[$i] . ' - ' . $end_locations[$i] . "\n";
    echo $start_dates[$i] . ' - ' . $end_dates[$i] . "\n";
}
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
Location_one - Location_two
02/11/2020 - 02/17/2020
Location_seven - Location_nine
02/21/2020 - 02/26/2020
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/EB4Kc)